# How do you handle complex redirects with Amazon s3 static hosting?

Tags: amazon-s3, redirect

We recently moved a site from a blog site to a static site hosted on s3 using cloudfront. When it came to applying the massive list of 301 redirects we'd need after the consolidation we were stunned to say the least to read through s3's extremely limited and painfully dumb redirect system. Hopefully we're just totally wrong here.

- So, we have to use their json structure. got it.
- We have a limit of 50 rules... wtf? but ok. Maybe we can do that with regex...
- We can't use regex... starting to get speechless here
- We have to use literal strings... ok this is just plain dumb now.

We have probably 1000 urls to redirect here. Nevermind something like blog/? which would mean the slash is optional in regex and capture both "blog" and "blog/" as end url segments. Not possible here?

Has anyone set up complex redirects with the s3 static hosting redirect rule json nightmare?

Example...

```
[
    {
        "Condition": {
            "KeyPrefixEquals": "blog/"
        },
        "Redirect": {
            "ReplaceKeyWith": "blog.html"
        }
    },
]
```

This ONLY handles /blog/ and will do absolutely nothing for just /blog AND it redirects to the literal bucket url and not the domain... holy ... ok maybe we missed a setting somewhere in that wonderfully complicated panel.

So, clearly we don't understand something here. [The docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/how-to-page-redirect.html) are so limited you'd wonder who is ever using such basic examples in a real life scenario?

So, ultimately the question is - using s3 and cloudfront to use a bucket to host a static site that used to be dynamic - how do you use their json redirect system to handle something like this that used to be pretty easy in virtually every other capacity:

```
^blog/?$ blog.html

^blog/(.*)/? blog.html
```

Both of these rules would capture blog, blog/, and blog/anything and redirect them all back to blog.html. But not with s3! Unless you know of a way that we don't.

Comment: If you're using CloudFront, then I wouldn't bother with the S3 stuff, as it is so limited like you mention. I would use CloudFront Lambda@Edge to perform whatever redirects you need https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/example-function-redirect-url.html

Comment: Are you aware of the [Redirect requests for an object](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/how-to-page-redirect.html#redirect-requests-object-metadata)?

Comment: @MarkB I had looked into that but wasnt sure if it would charge us for redirects because lambda. You know how AWS docs go though. Even if I wanted to try this, the syntax is so far from regex that I have no idea how to set up even the basics.

Comment: @jellycsc - well, I saw that but I dont think what I'm trying to do is redirect objects. We're talking very normal 301 redirects. old url, new one. If there is no object representing an old url, then what am I using this utility for? Maybe it's obvious, but for me nothing in AWS is ever clear or useful. I pretty much always have to ask on stack overflow for actual code examples since the docs tend to omit all useful applications of the services.

Comment: Well I linked you to an example Lambda@Edge script that specifically does redirects. I think that's the best you can do with your current technology stack of S3 + CloudFront.